# How to send a Object composed by Models and List (or IEnumerable) Models using $.ajax?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, controller

this is my model object

```
public class VentaProd
{
    public IEnumerable<product> ListadoProductos {get; set;}
    public IEnumerable<account> ListadoClientes { get; set; }
    public sale Venta { get; set; }
}
```

If I use this code

```
$.ajax(
{
    type: "Post",
    dataType: "html",
    url: '@Url.Action("buscarproducto", "detalle")',
    data: {
        vp: @Model.Venta.id
    },
    success: function (data) {
        $('#divbuscar').html(data);
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("algo salio mal" + errorThrown);
    }
}
);
```

the before code works but my controller receive a null object, and if i change this code

```
data: {
    vp: @Model.Venta.id
},
```

by

```
data: {
    vp: @Model
},
```

the controller method is never called
unfortunately I could not use the first code because
my object `VentaProd` is not saved in database and this does not have a Id.

this is the controller method

```
public ActionResult buscarproducto(ejercicio1.Models.ClasesCombinadas.VentaProd vp=null)
{
    return PartialView(vp);
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to send to the controller. If your want to send the `id` property of `sale` then your method parameter needs to be `(int id)`. If your trying to post the whole model, then it needs to be `data: $('form').serialize(),`

Comment: why $('form')? i dont have any element which was a form. is there not problem?

Comment: You don't have a form? Are you not editing anything? In which case what on earth would be the point of sending a model to a view and then posting it back unchanged (unless your trying to degrade the performance of your app)

Comment: sorry, what do you refer with a form?  <form></form>??? because I have <div></div>

Comment: Yes I mean `<form>` tags. But what are you really trying to do here. Your controller method makes no sense. Why would you post a model from the view to the controller and then return a partial view of the model (which you already have in the view anyway)?

Comment: well its my first application,  i dont know if <form> tags is required, until now this runs fine

Comment: You need to explain what is is your trying to do. The code you have posted makes no sense.

Comment: My first view is the principal, here i load a partialview where the client (for a sale is selected) when its selected I call a partialview where its add the html to a div (the div where was the code for select a client), when this second partialview is loaded this execute 2 calls 1 for show products and the other for show sale's detail, in all a execute the same method (add the html to some div)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to send back the ID the selection, you need to change the signature of the controller method to match the type of the id only:

```
    public ActionResult buscarproducto(int? id=null)
```

If you want to have the model as a whole come back to the existing controller method you have, then you need to encode it:

```
    vp: @Json.Encode(Model.Venta)
```